# Split a number n into sum of n-1 + n-2 +

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I have a random number, e.g. 5

What could a formula be to return: 1+2+3+4+5 = 15?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about...if n is in A1:

```
=A1*A1/2+A1/2
```

Answer (score 0):

def formula(n)
 if (n <= 0) return 0;
 return n + formula(n-1);

Comment: interesting recursion, though David's answer is more elegant I think.